# Ubuntu DNS doesn't failover to the secondary when primary can't resolve?

Tags: 18.04, dns, netplan, resolv.conf

I'm running an Ubuntu 18.04 in our company. I tried to implement dual DNS server in our LAN.

DNS1: 192.168.1.1 (BIND9),
DNS2: 192.168.1.2 (dnsmasq)

Here is the config file in the client:

```
### cat netplan file ###

    network:
      version: 2
      renderer: networkd
      ethernets:
        ens3:
          addresses: [192.168.1.100/24]
          gateway4: 192.168.1.254
          nameservers:
            addresses: [192.168.1.1,192.168.1.2,8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]

### cat /etc/resolv.conf ###

nameserver 192.168.1.1
nameserver 192.168.1.2
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0
```

I just did a simple testing that comment out 1 dns entry`(test.example.com)` in primary DNS(192.168.1.1) and see if the client can resolve the domain name by secondary DNS(192.168.1.2).
But looks like the client cannot resolve the domain name by DNS2.
I have checked that DNS2 can ping `test.example.com`

```
ping: test.example.com: Name or service not known
```

How do I setup dual DNS in my Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are expecting your client to failover to the secondary DNS IP when a DNS record is returned as NXDOMAIN.

This will not happen in such a case. The secondary DNS will be used when the primary stops responding altogether. It has nothing to do with certain zones or records not resolving.